# Should we use Work flows for field updates?

Tags: workflow, governorlimits

Is this recommended to use work flows for `field update`? I read that if we use work flows for field updates then triggers are get called twice. First before calling work flows(As per Order of Execution) and once after updating field using work flows(As per Order of Execution) to make sure standard validations.

So system is calling triggers twice in one transaction and it may lead to salesforce governor limit. So my question is in what circumstances should  we use work flow rules?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what apex trigger code you already have in place. If it heavily uses things that have governor limits (like DML calls), then you could hit a governor limit when the trigger is called twice because of a worflow field update. But a trigger that cannot be called twice within one transaction without hitting the governor limits is probably written in a bad way and should be optimised anyway. Search for bulkification to get some ideas on that.

In general, you will want to use workflow field updates instead of updating fields via apex. First, workflow rules should always work with new Salesforce releases, whereas apex code could have to be updated to work with new realeases (although this does not happen often). Secondly, it is usually easier to change workflow rules than changing and deploying apex code.

If you do not have apex triggers, you don't have to worry at all.

Comment: Agreed; clicks before code keeps everything simpler and eases maintenance costs.

Comment: Workflow rules when possible, code otherwise. Mike has the right idea.